# Find a pair of numbers in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Given the matrix `A = [6 4 1; 1 4 3; 3  4 2;7 6 8]` and the array of pairs `b = [4 6; 4 1; 1 6]`, I want to find the pairs given in `b` in the rows of `A` without a `for` loop.

For example, the first pairs is (4,6) or (6,4) , which occurs in the first row of `A`.

Comment: `b` is not a vector. It is a matrix. And what will be the output for the given `A` and `B` matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you want to find the rows of `A` which contain the exact pairs given in `b`, this is how you can do it without a loop:

```
% Create a matrix of pairs in A
pairs = cat(3, A(:, 1:end-1), A(:, 2:end));

% Reshape b to use bsxfun
b_ = reshape(b', [1 1 size(b')]);

% Get the matches for the pairs and for the flipped pairs
indices =  all( bsxfun(@eq, pairs, b_), 3) | all( bsxfun(@eq, pairs, flip(b_,3)), 3);

% Find the indices of the rows with a match
row_indices = find(squeeze(any(any(indices,4),2)));
```

Please refer to [the reference on vectorization](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) for more information on how to make fast computations in Matlab without loops.

Comment: If i want to do this for a bigger matrix, that is A = [6 4 1 6; 1 4 3 1; 3  4 2 3;7 6 8 7], how can I modify the code?

Comment: The code should be the same. I have not explicitly used the dimensions of `A` and the implementation should be quite efficient.

Comment: I don't want to delete zeros, if code not find a pair.